# Adaptec 1220SA RAID 1 degraded - should I try to rebuild?

Tags: windows-8.1, raid, storage, raid-1, hardware-raid

I've got an old Windows 8.1 PC with an old RAID 1 array and a very low-end Adaptec 1220SA RAID controller. Adaptec Storage Manager (screenshot #1 below) shows one drive failed, the other OK. There's no additional information about the failure. There's an right-click "Rebuild Drive" option on the right-click menu in Adaptec Storage Manager.

[image]

I've tried to find more info online about this "rebuild drive" right-click command but the only documentation that mentions this is [in Japanese](http://support.express.nec.co.jp/usersguide/120lh_3/sg_asm.pdf) and Google Translate can't handle it. ;-(

Questions for someone who's familiar with Adaptec's older controllers and tools:

- Should I bother trying to Rebuild Drive using the right click option?  Or is this drive dead and I shouldn't bother-- just buy a new one?
- Is it risky to try to rebuild it-- can I mess up the other working drive?
- Is it worth troubleshooting cables, power supply connections, etc. or does this error imply the drive itself is hosed and I should replace the drive?
- When the system boots, it shows both drives in a "Healthy" status. See screenshot #3. Why does it show as Healthy on boot but failed in the Windows and BIOS array configuration utilities?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you don't rebuild the raid array, and the other drive fails, your data is gone.

Comment: Yep, I'm definitely going to rebuild the array. But I'm confused about why I see a "rebuild" right-click option on the failed drive. Is it possible that rebuilding that drive will fix the problem? The main issue here is that documentation I've found online for Adaptec's tools is scanty at best. It's unclear exactly what kind of problem "failed" means. If rebuilding that drive will fix it, that's ideal. Otherwise I can just buy a new $50 1TB replacement.  But before I go buy one I want to make sure there's not another easy and safe way to fix the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't read into the rebuild option being on the failed drive as anything.